# Django Static compressed files not rendering on Firefox

Tags: django, firefox, django-staticfiles, django-static, firefox-8

I am using **[django-static](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-static)** for **optimization** of static stylesheets and javascripts. Now all these scripts and css properties are being loaded in Chrome and on Safari. But for some reason they are not loading in Firefox. Am i doing something wrong? Does Firefox require some other setting ?

If additional information is required please comment. I will add it. (Firefox version 8)

EDIT:
After checking Chrome and Firefox using **Firebug**. I found that the **script** being rendered was with the **source** as

```
src="/media/js/hawk\foo_boo_ajax_too_forms_refer_moder.1323864494.js
```

Now this is being **interpreted by Chrome** as

```
src="/media/js/hawk/foo_boo_ajax_too_forms_refer_moder.1323864494.js
```

But firefox is not able to interpret it. Is this a firefox issue or do i have to change the "/"? (The link or source being generated is by django-static. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above said issue ,is a bug in django-static. This issue crops up on windows machine.(On windows it mixes up file system path and the url.)I have contacted the developer, and I think the issue will be solved soon. Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 1):

Per the URI spec, you need to change to '/'.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have the correct `Content-Type` and `Content-Encoding` headers set for your js and css files.

Comment: the content type are correct. The content encoding shouldn't matter because django-static does not gzip the files.